# Implementing an iterator copy constructor

Tags: c++

How can I properly implement a copy constructor for my iterator, knowing that the pointer to the data object is private? Do I need to create an accessor for this pointer? Isn't this a bad thing?

Comment: Likely, you need no copy constructor or assignment operator for your iterator (If so, you might have a questionable design). You might provide an example.

Comment: @DieterLücking I actually don't need one it seems, thank you for the remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you define a copy constructor for an iterator inside the implementation of the iterator itself, there is no need to make the hidden pointer accessible, with or without an accessor: the copy constructor will have access to it even if it is private, so there's nothing to worry about:

```
template <class T>
class MyIter {
    T *private_ptr;
public:
    MyIter(const MyIter<T> &other) : private_ptr(other.private_ptr) {}
    ... // More constructors and member functions
};
```

Answer (score 0):

All member functions of a class have access to the data members of the class.  This also applies to different objects of the same type.

```
class Foo()
{
private: 
    int bar;
public:
    void foobar(Foo & different) { bar = different.bar; }
};
```

Comment: @DieterLücking `foobar()` is a function not a constructor.